# Jeet can't be installed with stylus -u jeet -w -c command

Tags: css-frameworks

I think Jeet was recently changed its code and i am having trouble installing and deploying jeet. When I run the command, i get nothing. Its struck. I am on mac.

```
stylus -u jeet -w -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Replied to you on [Github](https://github.com/mojotech/jeet/issues/111) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeetFramework/status/401118668844568576) but no problem.

In Jeet 4, in an effort to make Jeet more modular, we took out the `jeet create` and `jeet watch` commands in favor of turning Jeet into a Stylus library only.

To use:

`npm install -g stylus jeet
cd ~/your/styl/folder
stylus -u jeet -w`

If you're looking for a boilerplate check out https://github.com/mojotech/jeet-html

If you're looking for a boilerplate/watcher check out https://github.com/mojotech/jeet-roots